# Python, pass a list with files names to work with "with open"

Tags: python, arrays, list, arguments, parameter-passing

```
import os

counter = len(os.listdir())-1 #counts files in this directory and safes the number of files-1 (.py file) in counter var
i = 1 #used for while loop to generate the amount of elements in the list
value = 0 #starting value of the filename
a = [] #list

#loop to create the list a
while i <= counter: #starting at file one until last file (counter var)
    file = f"{value:#0{10}x}"[2:] + ".txt" #files are named hex, this converts the number in hex with 8 digits an removes the 0x th the beginning. it adds the .txt extension
    a.append(file) #saves the filename in the list of a
    i += 1
    value += 1

b = input("Enter keyword: ")

"""function takes file_name from a (list) and string_to_search b
opens file, search for the word and prints a string from start of the word to the next period (.)"""

def search_string_in_file(file_name, string_to_search):
    for element in file_name:
        results = ""
        with open(file_name, 'r' , encoding='latin1') as read_obj:
            for line in read_obj:
                word_index = line.find(string_to_search)
                if (word_index != -1):
                    period_index = line.find('.', word_index+len(string_to_search))
                    print(line[word_index:period_index+1])

search_string_in_file(a, b)
```

files are named "8 digit hex (0-f) lowercase".txt
So my issue now is, that I can't pass the list as argument to the function

I want so search all the files for that specific word and print the sentence starting from the word to the next period

I tested to print(a) before running the function and it gave the correct results like:
['00000000.txt', '00000001.txt', ... , '00000fa7.txt']

now I wanna pass 00000000.txt to the function and do the thing, then 00000001.txt and so on

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? You have a folder with the files you need to work on. That folder contains the text files + the .py file? Is that correct?

Comment: that is correct, that folder ONLY contains those .txt files and that one .py file, nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, can you post the logs or console feedbacks?

---

**Analysis**

Testing your code I get

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Looking at *search_string_in_file* method I see that the first '*for*' cycle is on the '*file_name*' list and each element is labelled as '*element*'

```
for element in file_name:
```

however you execute the 'open' on the '*file_name*' instead of '*element*'

```
with open(file_name, 'r' , encoding='latin1') as read_obj:
```

---

**Solution**

I think the code reported below should work for the *search_string_in_file* function:

```
def search_string_in_file(file_name, string_to_search):
    for element in file_name:
        results = ""
        with open(element, 'r' , encoding='latin1') as read_obj:
            for line in read_obj:
                word_index = line.find(string_to_search)
                if (word_index != -1):
                    period_index = line.find('.', word_index+len(string_to_search))
                    print(line[word_index:period_index+1])
```

Comment: That's alread it. wow, nice work.
so what the error message meant is in "with open" I try to open the whole list instead of one element by the other?

Comment: Yeah exactly. You opened a for loop but you stilled used the list you passed in as argument instead of the `element` part of the for loop.
I had a different solution that doesnt require a list but if this is enough then it doesnt really matter.